# Malformed JSON on var_dump

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to post to an API using CURL. 
When i var_dump on the curl_exec, I get a message "Malformed JSON". I think my JSON Looks pretty good and it should be working. Any idea why it isnt? Here's

The result of my JSON looks like this:

> {"AmountDebit":10,"Currency":"EUR","Invoice":"testinvoice
>   123","Services":{"ServiceList":[{"Action":"Pay","Name":"ideal","Parameters":[{"Name":"issuer","Value":"ABNANL2A"}]}]}}

my code:

```
<?php
$postArray = array(
    "Currency" => "EUR",
    "AmountDebit" => 10.00,
    "Invoice" => "testinvoice 123",
    "Services" => array(
        "ServiceList" => array(
            array(
                "Action" => "Pay",
                "Name" => "ideal",
                "Parameters" => array(
                    array(
                        "Name" => "issuer",
                        "Value" => "ABNANL2A"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

ksort($postArray);

$post = json_encode($postArray);

echo $post . '<br><br>';

$md5  = md5($post, true);
$post = base64_encode($md5);

echo '<b>MD5 from json</b> ' . $md5 . '<br><br>';
echo '<b>base64 from MD5</b> ' . $post . '<br><br>';

$websiteKey = '-';
$uri        = strtolower(urlencode('https://testcheckout.buckaroo.nl/json/transaction'));
$nonce      = 'nonce_' . rand(0000000, 9999999);
$time       = time();

$hmac       = $websiteKey . 'POST' . $uri . $time . $nonce . $post;
$s          = hash_hmac('sha256', $hmac, '-', true);
$hmac       = base64_encode($s);
$url= 'https://testcheckout.buckaroo.nl/json/transaction';

echo 'Authorization: hmac ' .$websiteKey.':'.$hmac .':'.$nonce . ':'.$time;


$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: hmac ' .$websiteKey.':'.$hmac .':'.$nonce . ':'.$time;
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen(json_encode($postArray)); 


print_r($headers);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postArray));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($result);
curl_close($curl);

?>
```

Comment: Maybe because `ServiceList` has an extra array ?

Comment: It passes on jsonlint.com, so it should work.

Comment: Contact buckaroo with this problem you are using the PHP example posted on thier API page ( https://dev.buckaroo.nl/Apis/Description/json#top ).. the wierd thing the C# and Javascript code are using two keys WebsiteKey and SecretKey.. The PHP code only uses .websiteKey so the PHP code looks complety wrong.

Comment: `$headers[] = 'Authorization: hmac ' .$websiteKey.':'.$hmac .':'.$nonce . ':'.$time;`  in the  API manual https://dev.buckaroo.nl/Apis/Description/json#top it clear "Authorization: hmac ABCD1234:WISKbwwMbWhMRSRJc0jFtg/LIvB9vM5VWPvfVa0JnMc=:134ee2ec5c9d43d7acfae9190ec7eb83:1434973589" is build up out out "ABCD1234: Website Key:" but iám missing Secret Key within the PHP code..

Comment: @RaymondNijland i removed it for privacy issues but its there normally

Answer (score 0):

As previous comments says : your json is valid and seems to respect Buckaroo spec (https://testcheckout.buckaroo.nl/json/Docs/Api/POST-json-Transaction). Try to use the JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION flag to json_encode, to force round number in decimal (1 => 1.0 )